# c# multiple file variable access

Tags: c#

I am trying to crete a c# program that uses phone cam to take a photo but i need the ip of the phone webcam so i use a form text field and buttons. When i click the button the ipAddres String has to change to the new value at the text box but i can't use that string in the form1.cs file. Please help!

There is my Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            String IpAddres;
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

And there is my Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void sendIpAddres(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //!There I want to give the new value to ipAddres!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have any questions, please ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `ViewModel` class for your `DataContext`. Whenever you use a control in your view (xaml file), you can bind for instance, your `TextBox` to a property from `ViewModel`, so there is no need of writing any code behind at all (which is bad practice - use MVVM framework in this case : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx).

So if I understand well, you can use the following example (with code behind):

### **MainWindow**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ViewModel localDataContext;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var myViewModel = new ViewModel();
        DataContext = myViewModel;
        localDataContext = (ViewModel) DataContext;
    }

    private void sendIpAddres(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MyTextBox.Text = localDataContext.ipAddress;
    }
}
```

### **ViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string ipAddress { get; set; }

    // do whatever you want with your ipAddress
}
```

---

### UPDATE (using binding)

### **MainWindow.xaml**

```
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" Text="{Binding ipAddress, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0,0,434,302"/>
```